# How to change real symbol to complex in sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbols

In the code below, I define real Symbols to take the limit in sympy then use subs to get the numeric result.

```
#To take the limit with unknown values, I have to define real symbols
from sympy import *

x = symbols("x")
H = symbols("H")
p = symbols("p")
#-----
# Position_1
#-----
dict = {H: 5,p:3,x:1}
###  Some operations
H = Symbol("H", real = True, positive = True )
p = Symbol("p", real = True, positive = True )
h = (H*p + (1 - p)**H - 1)/(H*p) 
dh = limit(h,p,1,'+')
#
g = H*x**2 + h
poly = Poly(g,x)
print("poly",poly)
#-----
# Position_2
#-----
dict = {H: 5,p:3,x:1}
Numeric_result = poly.subs(dict)
print("Numeric_result = " ,Numeric_result )
```

the output is :

```
Numeric_result = H*x**2 + 1 + (1 - p)**H/(H*p) - 1/(H*p)
```

While it should substitute H and p,x

```
Numeric_result = 3.8
```

I think the problem is that sympy defines symbols globally therefore can not substitute them.

I tried the following solutions but didn't work.

changing assumptions to remove real symbol and compute g [Sympy_ assumption]  [1]: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/assumptions/assume.html

and also right before computing g

```
H = Symbol("H", real = False, complex= True)
```

Comment: In this question, there is no problem with Symbols (I found out after the first response) So I had to move the dictionary  to position 2. Then subs works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When doing `subs` make the keys the symbols you are trying to replace. It won't matter if your Symbols are "vanilla" type with no assumptions, but in your case you have assumptions. This works on your example:

```
>>> dict = {H: 5, p:3, x:1}
>>> poly.subs(dict)
19/5
```

Comment: Thank you @smichr!  The problem is in subs indeed. I had to change the dictionary position before the Numeric_result not at the beginning of the code.